# Question about Anderson Localization and a specific theorem (RAGE)

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations, spectral-theory, localization, self-adjoint-operators

I have a question with a theorem which appears in a text called “Invitation to Random Schrödinger Operators”, in unit 7.

---

Theorem 7.7. Let $H$ be a selfadjoint operator on Hilbert Space, take $\psi \in H_{pp}$ and let $\Lambda_L$ denote a cube in $\mathbb Z^d$ centered at the origin with side length $2L+1$. Then:

(1) $$\lim_{L \to \infty} \sup_{t \geq 0} \left(\sum_{x \in \Lambda_L} |e^{-itH} \psi(x)|^2 \right) = ||\psi||^2$$

and

(2) $$\lim_{L \to \infty} \sup_{t \geq 0} \left(\sum_{x \notin \Lambda_L} |e^{-itH} \psi(x)|^2 \right) = 0 $$

---

Proof: Since $e^{-itH}$ is unitary, we have for all $t$

$$||\psi||^2 =||e^{-itH} \psi||^2 = \sum_{x \in \Lambda_L } |e^{-itH} \psi(x)|^2 + \sum_{x \notin \Lambda_L} |e^{-itH}\psi(x)|^2 $$

Above we saw that the expression is valid for eigenfunctions $\psi$. To prove it for other vectors in $H_{pp}$ we introduce the following notation: By $P_L$ we denote the projection onto $C\Lambda_L$. Then equation (2) claims that:

$$ ||P_L e^{-itH} \psi||^2 \to 0$$

uniformly in $t$ as $L \to \infty$. If $\psi$ is a finite linear combination of eigenfunctions, say $\psi=\sum_{m=1}^M \alpha_k \psi_k$, $H\psi_k=E_k \psi_k$, then:

(3) $$ ||P_L e^{-itH} \psi || = || \sum_{m=1}^M \alpha_k P_L e^{-itH} \psi_k || \leq \sum_{m=1}^M |\alpha_k| ||P_L e^{-itH} \psi_k || = \sum_{m=1}^M |\alpha_k| ||P_L e^{-itE_k} \psi_k|| = \sum_{m=1}^M |\alpha_k| ||P_L \psi_k||$$

**From this moment, it is that I begin to have problems to understand**

> By taking $L$ large enough, each term in the sum above can be made smaller then $(\sum_{m=1}^M |\alpha_k|)^{-1} \varepsilon$. If now $\psi$ is an arbitrary element of $H_{pp}$ , there is a linear combination of eigenfunctions $\psi^{(M)} = \sum_{m=1}^M \alpha_k \psi_k$ such that $||\psi-\psi^{(M)}|| < \varepsilon $
> $||P_L e^{-itH} \psi|| \leq ||P_L e^{-itH} \psi^{(M)} || + ||P_L e^{-itH} (\psi - \psi^{(M)}) || \leq ||P_L e^{-itH} \psi^{(M)}  || + || \psi - \psi^{(M)}||$

GUYS I can’t understand how $||P_L e^{-itH} (\psi - \psi^{(M)} ) || \leq || \psi - \psi^{(M)}||$

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can break this down into two components. The first one being that $P_L$ is a projection so $||P_Le^{-itH}(\psi-\psi^{(M)})||\leq ||e^{-itH}(\psi-\psi^{(M)})||$ . Then you use that $e^{-itH}$ is unitary so $||e^{-itH}(\psi-\psi^{(M)})|| = ||\psi-\psi^{(M)}||$